# Changing order in stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I'm struggling with fixing the order of my stacked bar chart despite having read through all the examples I could find. It is definitely not stacking based on the order in my dataframe, which seems to be a common answer.

I've managed to change the labels to the proper order, but the plot itself is being stubborn.

I would like to enter the order manually since it does not follow a pattern.

[image]

**data**

```
sdi_table_2<-read.table(text="'Over 50' 'Under 50'
'Intellectual Disability' 154814 214279
'Other Mental Health' 1387315 1012520
Injuries 240033 116167
Musculo-Skeletal 2041162 447212
'Nervous System' 530179 272756
'Circulatory, Respiratory, Endocrine, and Neoplasms' 1281261 260737
'Other and Unknown' 404973 212136", header=TRUE, check.names=F)
sdi_data_2<-as.data.frame.matrix(sdi_table_2)
sdi_data_2$type<-rownames(sdi_data_2)
sdi_data_2<-melt(sdi_data_2,id.vars = c("type"), value.name = "Beneficiaries")
sdi_data_2$variable <- as.character(sdi_data_2$variable)
colnames(sdi_data_2)[2] <- "Age"
factor(sdi_table_2$type, levels = sdi_table_2$type, ordered = TRUE)
```

**plot**

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(y = Beneficiaries, x = Age, fill = type),
           data = sdi_data_2,
           stat = "identity") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(label = comma) +
  scale_fill_manual(
    name = "",
    values = c(
      "Injuries" = "orange2",
      "Circulatory, Respiratory, Endocrine, and Neoplasms" =
        "sandybrown",
      "Nervous System" = "peachpuff",
      "Intellectual Disability" = "skyblue2",
      "Musculo-Skeletal" = "royalblue3",
      [enter image description here][1] "Other and Unknown" =
        "lightgoldenrod1",
      "Other Mental Health" = "royalblue1"
    ),
    breaks = c(
      "Other and Unknown",
      "Injuries",
      "Circulatory, Respiratory, Endocrine, and Neoplasms",
      "Nervous System",
      "Musculo-Skeletal",
      "Other Mental Health",
      "Intellectual Disability"
    )
  )
```

Comment: There are issues in your code. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your problem. 
But you can order your type using the factor's level.

```
sdi_data_2$type <- factor(sdi_data_2$type, levels = c("Circulatory, Respiratory, Endocrine, and Neoplasms","Nervous System","Injuries","Other Mental Health","Other and Unknown","Musculo-Skeletal","Intellectual Disability"))
sdi_data_2$Age <- factor(sdi_data_2$Age,levels = c("Under 50","Over 50"))
```

and then to plot:

```
ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(y = Beneficiaries, x = Age, fill = type), data = sdi_data_2, stat = "identity") + theme_bw()
```

This is the result: 
[image]